# Question to Blender developers on file handling in Windows

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, windows, development

On one of our Windows 10 PCs we are not able to access render output files of Blender v.2.78 using windows explorer: The file is listed in the file selection dialog in Blender, but is not visible to Windows.

It seems that this behavior is observed by some other people in the net as well, and so far the only solution seems to be to do a repair reinstall Windows.

Fearing other complications of a windows repair, we looked further into the problem.

We checked every previous blender version until we were be able to locate a version that does not exhibit this problem, and found that v.2.61 does not have this behavior.

So, on a particular PC, render output files of Blender 2.62 and above are created, but not visible in Windows Explorer (display of hidden and system files enabled). Output files of 2.61 are visible on the same PC.

Could someone related to or knowledgeable on the development of Blender comment on whether there has been a change in output file creation routines when switching from v.2.61 to v.2.62?

Many thanks in advance,
Arifi Koseoglu

Comment: Nice investigation work this is very useful info for the Blender developers and in the right way to find a proper fix. Unfortunately this is not the right place to expose this problem. We are mostly end users, and developers don't often hang out around these parts. You should probably reports this to the [Blender bug tracker](http://developer.blender.org/), sharing as much relevant information as possible, or if you plan to contribute contact the developers directly in the [Developers Mailing](https://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-committers)

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: Many thanks for the pointers  Duarte Farrajota Ramos, I will proceed as you suggested. Best regards. -arifi

Comment: Hello cetagon, Do you mean Windows file sharing? No - file is not visible in Windows realm. Or is there a "share" mechanism in Blender? I am very new in this world..

Comment: @ArifiKoseoglu Users will not be notified of new comments unless you put '@' in front of their (correctly spelled) username.

Comment: This question does not have enough info for others to help you. Please post in ages that shoe what kind of render settings and output format you are dealing wit. SHARE a flexible in thus case means upload the file to a hosting site so that others can download it and inspect it please use giantcowfilms blendexchange to upload

Comment: If The Issue Is With Only One Machine With Windows 10, But Not In Others Please Note What Is Different On That Particular Piece Of hardware. It's hard to guess  without the proper information

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos Many thanks for the pointers, I will proceed as you suggested. Best regards. -arifi

Comment: @cetagon I believe that there is a misunderstanding. I cannot access the file on the disk to share it. My problem is not with the output file itself, nor the process of creating it. It is about being able to access the generated file on the file system.

Comment: Agree with @cegaton a test file or  screenshot would be handy here... what is the name of the rendered image (Render Result???) what is the filepath it's saved to?   What exactly do you mean by the file selection dialogue?

Comment: As the original poster, I agree with @Duarte Farrajota Ramos and iKlsR 's comment saying "This question appears to be about an issue caused by a bug in Blender. These should be reported to the official bug tracker." I have reported it to the official bug tracker. Is there something that I need to do to prevent further communication on this question?